Estne in lingua Latina verbum quod significat vertere quod censes, ut Anglica phrasa "change one's mind" vel Croaticum verbum "predomisliti"?
Estne in lingua Latina verbum quod significat vertere quod censes, ut Anglica phrasa "change one's mind" vel Croaticum verbum "pre-do-misliti" ("trans-ad-cogitare")?
Exempli gratia, multi discipuli in lyceo volunt FERIT-e scientiae computatrorum studere, sed nesciunt quomodo appellantur scholae quas auscultabunt secundo anno ("Objektno orijentirano programiranje", "Razvoj programske podrške po objektno orijentiranim načelima"...). Si solummodo dicam eis quomodo appellantur scholae quas auscultabunt secundo anno, ii discipuli probabiliter... Quid agant?
SUMMARY: Is there a Latin verb meaning "to change one's mind"?

If by "change one's mind" we mean "alter one's opinion," there are a number of suitable Latin idioms. This list is not exhaustive, and I have drawn the examples exclusively from Cicero.

sententiam mutare
de sententia decedere
sententiā desistere
opinionem mutare

In Pro Murena, Cicero engages with Zeno's opinion that the wise man never changes his opinion (sapientem ... sententiam mutare numquam), that it is in fact shameful to do so (mutare sententiam turpe est). He then contrasts that with the more moderate Platonic and Aristotelian ideal of the wise man, who sometimes does change or renounce a previous opinion (ipsum sapientem ... placari, quod dixerit interdum, si ita rectius sit, mutare, de sententia decedere aliquando).
In Academica, we see sententiā desistere used several times in the context of giving up a held position after encountering compelling counterarguments. For instance, after Lucullus finishes speaking, Hortensius is so impressed that he urged Cicero (perhaps facetiously) to give up on the spot: "Hortensius autem vehementer admirans ... me quoque ... coepit hortari ut sententia desisterem."
In Topica, we have a pithy dictum: "It's hard to change the mind of the common people" (vulgi opinio mutari vix potest).
However, it is also possible that "to change one's mind" refers more to a change of plans or intentions than an opinion. In this case, consilium (com)mutare works. Caesar, for instance, enjoys the phrase "(com)mutato consilio".
Nota bene: The perhaps seemingly similar expression animum mutare has a broader meaning, more about changing one's mindset or character in a broader sense. Perhaps it even more closely approximates the English idiom "to have a change of heart."

FWIW, there is Psalm 110:

Iuravit Dominus et non pænitebit eum / The Lord has sworn and will not
change his mind (waver, take it back, break his vow, repent in other translations)

Though the main meaning of pæniteo is to make sorry and to cause to repent, the Vulgate seems to prefer that of to repent, including the somehow softer sense of change one's mind.
